# The definition of phrasal verb "call out" in a line

Tags: phrase-meaning

I am currently reading [**this article,**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/call-out_1), the first line says,

> If ESPN’s “The Last Dance” has reinforced anything, it’s how demanding — and, sometimes, abusive — Michael Jordan could be of his teammates. Jordan belittled team general manager Jerry Krause in the first episode, and **called out** Ron Harper and Toni Kukoc in the second. Jordan even questioned Scottie Pippen’s decision to have surgery.

Would this verb "call out" here may be mean "to get them out"? (I feel like so.)

Or from [**Collins,**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/call-out)

> If you call someone out, you order or request that they come to help, especially in an emergency.

Could anyone help?

Thank you in advance for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sense here is one of the secondary meanings of "call out".  Wiktionary has it as its [sense 3](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/call_out#Verb)

> (transitive, idiomatic, colloquial) To challenge, criticize, denounce.
>   Synonyms: denounce, point out, charge

Jordan criticised or denounced Ron and Tony.  Calling someone out often means broadcasting or pointing out the mistake or lies that someone has made.

Comment: Thanks! Can't imagine Jordan even "called out" (especially) Ron Harper and Kukoc...

Comment: But that is exactly what the quote says.  He was demanding, abusive and belittling. Just because he was good at basketball doesn't make him a nice guy