# The meaning of "call out" in this context

Tags: word-usage

Reading [**this article**](https://news.yahoo.com/higher-usual-number-atlanta-police-024316531.html), I have had an agony like [**asking before the definition of call out.**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/245361/the-definition-of-phrasal-verb-call-out-in-a-line).

I am not perfectly sure what call out means for such as this line.

> The Atlanta Police Department said Wednesday that it was experiencing "a higher than usual number of **call outs**."

According to the [**Collins**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/call-out), I speculate the verb is used by the definition of the **British English's**

> 3. (transitive)
>    to order ( workers) to strike

So my questions are,

1 Am I correct in my speculation?

2 Even though Collins says it the British way of saying, doesn't it matter?

Thank you for your time

Comment: It means _times when the police were called out (to an emergency)_, as in the definition supplied by Bruce. Nothing to do with being 'called out on strike'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1 Am I correct in my speculation?

No - here you have the wrong meaning.

Call out can [also be defined as](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/call+out):

> **to summon**

So here, call out means when the emergency services/any other service attends a call/request that they received.

> 2 Even though Collins says it the British way of saying, doesn't it matter?

I live in Britain and it is common here to use that, not sure about other countries.

Comment: Isn't it rather the meaning of "call out" in your dictionary?(summon)

Comment: @Kentaro What do you mean?

Comment: I mean your answer "To demand or ask for the presence of" is one of the definitions of "call", not "call out".

Comment: @Kentaro It has the same meaning but I changed it

Comment: I think you are not answering my second question straightly, but thanks to the dictionary you posted I guess this verb in the meaning "to summon" is being used in the U.S. SI I would like to select yours.

Comment: @Kentaro Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

call-out
/ˈkôlˌout/
noun
1.
an instance of being summoned, especially in order to deal with an emergency or to do repairs.

Definition of call out (Entry 2 of 2)
transitive verb

1: to summon into action
call out troops
2: to challenge to a duel
3: to order on strike
call out the workers